# "avdmanager is missing from Android SDK" while setting up Emulator in VS Code [Ubuntu]

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

`/opt/Android/cmdline-tools/tools/bin` is where the sdk is stored

I have added it to path aswell with

`export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/Android/` &
`export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$PATH` and restarting with `source`

And yet when I try to create android emulator with VScode i get an error

[VScode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aYCS.png)

`Flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 5.15.0-48-generic,
    locale en_IN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Can you please run Flutter Doctor and post your response from cmd.

Comment: sure! I have edited the post. I also configured with ```flutter config --android-sdk /opt/Android``` 

/opt/Android is where the tools are unzipped but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you download Android Studio, it should automatically configure everything for you and you can then use android emulators without any issues. Flutter doctor seems to suggest doing the same as well.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I followed [this](https://PATH=%22$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH%22) custom installation guide and it worked!